# Deserialize JSON Root Array

Tags: json

I'm having so trouble deserializing a JSON stream that contains an array as the root:

```
[
    {
        "object": {
                     "property1":"000000",
                     "property2":"000000"
                  }
    },
    {
        "object": {
                     "property1":"000000",
                     "property2":"000000"
                  }
    }
]
```

I tried using JSON.deserializeUntyped and assigning to a Map, but I keep getting a "invalid conversion runtime type LIST to MAP". This method worked fine when I was dealing with single JSON objects, but loading multiples into an array trips this error. Should I be using a different type for deserialization?

Comment: Delete comma after `property2`. (I deleted my answer to add this comment)

Comment: Comma removed. This was just a quick example I threw together to get the idea across!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to cast it into a `List<Object>`, and for each element in the list, you can access the values as a `Map<Object,Object>`.

Answer (score 2):

As well as containing the extra commas, the JSON you show is an array of objects. You have to type convert it in two steps:

```
String s = '[{"object": {"property1":"000000","property2":"000000"}},'
        + '{"object": {"property1":"000000","property2":"000000"}}]';

List<Object> l = (List<Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped (s);
for (Object o : l) {
    Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>) o;
    System.debug('>>> m=' + m);
}
```